# what is the disadvantage using hostSNI(*) in traefik TCP route mapping

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

Now I am using `HostSNI(`*`)` to mapping the TCP service like `mysql\postgresql...` in traefik 2.2.1 in Kubernetes cluster v1.18 . beacuse I am in my local machine and did not have a valid certification. This is the config:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
    name: mysql-ingress-tcp-route
    namespace: middleware
spec:
    entryPoints:
        - mysql
    routes:
        - match: HostSNI(`*`)
          services:
            - name: report-mysqlha
                port: 3306
```

is config works fine in my local machine. But I still want to  know the side effect to using
`HostSNI(`*`)` mapping stratege. What is the disadvantege to using `HostSNI(`*`)` not a domain name? Is it possible to using a fake domain name in my local machine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of the latest Traefik docs ([2.4 at this time](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule_1)):

> If both HTTP routers and TCP routers listen to the same entry points, the TCP routers will apply before the HTTP routers

> It is important to note that the Server Name Indication is an extension of the TLS protocol. Hence, only TLS routers will be able to specify a domain name with that rule. However, non-TLS routers will have to explicitly use that rule with * (every domain) to state that every non-TLS request will be handled by the router.

Therefore, to answer your questions:

- Using `` HostSNI(`*`) `` is the only reasonable way to use an `ingressRouteTCP` *without* tls -- since you're explicitly asking for a TCP router and TCP doesn't speak TLS.

  - I've had mixed success with `ingressRouteTCP` and `` HostSNI(`some.fqdn.here`) `` with a `tls:` section, but it does appear to be a supported configuration as per [2](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-ingressroutetcp)
- One possible "disadvantage" to this (airquotes because it's subjective) is: This configuration means that any traffic that routes to your `entrypoint` (i.e. `mysql`) will be routed via this `ingressRouteTCP`

  - Consider: if for some reason you had another `ingressRoute` with the same `entrypoint`, the `ingressRouteTCP` would take precedence as per [1](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule_1)
  - Consider: if, for example you wanted to route multiple different `mysql` services via the same `entrypoint: mysql`, you wouldn't be able to based on this configuration

Comment: "If both HTTP routers and TCP routers listen to the same entry points, the TCP routers will apply before the HTTP routers" did not find this in the official docs it helped me a lot thanks !

Answer (score 10):

For those needing an example of TCP with TLS passthrough and SNI routing

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: test-https
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure # maps to port 443 by default
  routes:
  - match: HostSNI(`my.domain.com`)
    services:
    - name: myservice
      port: 443
  tls:
    passthrough: true
```